# What's the connection between Mike and Artie?

Tags: plot-explanation, noel

In the film "Noel" what is the connection between Mike and Artie? Artie believes Mike is the reincarnated soul of his wife, which I'm guessing is certainly not true.

I believe that Artie is to serve as a warning to Mike. Mike needs to learn how to deal with his jealous behavior because Artie's life story turned out the exact same way that Mike's seems to be heading, due to jealousy.

However, that doesn't answer questions about how Artie knew what kind of cookies Mike liked. He just randomly gives Mike butter cookies, claiming they were his wife's favorite as well.

It also doesn't answer the question about the glass angel from Artie's past being the very same angel that Mike had broken in a jealous rage.